# Global filter in primeng p-table doesn't work for complex row data

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

[Primefaces primeng filter p-table example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter) - global filtering doesn't work for complex data.
Example uses model:

```
export interface Car {
vin?;
year?;
brand?;
color?;
price?;
saleDate?;    
}
```

If we add field *engine* to car interface:

```
export interface Engine {
type?;
power?;
atRpm?;
}
```

And add column *Engine* to the template to display `rowData.engine.type` data, global filter is not working for this column.  How to solve this?

I'd prefer to avoid data flattening if possible. Because it should be done on large amount of data and the original model is productively used in application.

Comment: Use custom sorting method - how would you expect table to compare 2 objects of unknown structure by itself huh?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.
Obviously, implementation similar to Sorting example (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort) should solve the case.

Comment: @Antoniossss: this solution works for sorting but not for global filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should works:

```
[globalFilterFields]="['engine.type']"
```

Add other fields if you want :

```
'engine.type', 'engine.power'
```

Comment: adding `[globalFilterFields]="['vim','brand','year','engine.type']"` directive to `p-table tag` solved the problem.
Thx!

Comment: What if engine is multiple is array of values